# How to get the first and last day of each year in a loop with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a range of years, I want to know the first and last day or date of each year. because I need to calculate all activities that have been done in each years. here is my code:

```
$years = range(2015, date('Y'));

foreach ($years as $year) {

   echo "Number of activities" . $year . "<br/>";
}
```

I need to have the strat and end date or day of all years.
I can get the first and last day in the way as below but it not a good salution:

```
// for 2015
$firstDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january 2015'));
$lastDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december 2015'));
// for 2016
$firstDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january 2016'));
$lastDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december 2016'));
.
.
.
// until 2021
```

When the number of year increase it's not possible manually. Because i need to display them in a chart.
Can anybody help me pelease ?

Comment: Well first of all, what is stopping you from simply making the year portion in `strtotime('first day of january 2015')` dynamic? You do know how string concatenation works, don't you?

Comment: Second, do you really need to "calculate" that? My years always start on the first of January, and end on the 31st of December - assuming yours probably do, too, you might as well just append `-01-01` and `-12-31` directly to each year value you are looping over there.

Comment: it blacks me because it's a dynamic solution, I need each year to add one year more dynamicaly.

Comment: And I just told you two different ways to make this dynamic ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
$start_year = '2015';
$last_year = date('Y');

for($start_year; $start_year <= $last_year; $start_year++){
    echo $firstDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of january {$start_year}"));
    echo $lastDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of december {$start_year}"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mainul Hasan, that is exactly what i want

Comment: You're most welcome!

Comment: @WahidAMINI, if it works for you, can mark it as a helpful answer; someone will be benefitted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

```
$years = range(2015, date('Y'));

$array = [];

foreach ($years as $year) {

    echo "Number of activities " . $year . "<br/>";

    $obj = (object)[];

    $obj->$firstDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january ' . $year));
    $obj->$lastDayOfYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december ' . $year));

    $array[$year] = $obj;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Shahid